# Refactor plain request data parsing using symfony Form Component

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

So I have a controller with this action method here:

```
public function addAction(Request $request)
{
    $tournamentId = $request->request->get('tournament_id');
    $externalId = $request->request->get('external_id');
    $eventDate = $request->request->get('event_date');

    if (!is_numeric($tournamentId) || !is_numeric($externalId) || empty($eventDate)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Invalid POST data');
    }

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $tournament = $em->getRepository('BakingBankCoreBundle:TournamentGame')->find($tournamentId);

    if (empty($tournament)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Invalid tournament ID');
    }

    $entity = new TournamentInstance();
    $entity->setTournament($tournament);
    $entity->setExternalId($externalId);
    $entity->setEventDate(new DateTime($eventDate));

    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush();

    return new JsonResponse(['id' => $entity->getId()]);
}
```

My colleague wants me to refactor this to use a form. The catch is - the TournamentInstance fields are as follows:

```
/**
 * @var TournamentGame
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TournamentGame")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tournament_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE", nullable=false)
 */
private $tournament;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="external_id", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
 */
private $externalId;

/**
 * @var DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="event_date", type="date", nullable=false)
 */
private $eventDate;
```

The POST data is not sent from a twig form, but rather from an AJAX request in JS, where the data is collected from several positions in the code.

How could I make this happen and is it even worth it? I get that he wants everything to be standartized, but I think he's being even more idealist than I am (and that says a lot).

Comment: which version of symfony are you using ?

Comment: @Heah - 2.7, but planning to move this project to 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

Not need too much work as you just need to map your entity properties to form fields :

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateTimeType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

public function addAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new TournamentInstance();

    // you can set default value with $entity->setEventDate(new DateTime('tomorrow'))
    // before passing it as data to the form builder

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($entity) // set the default value
        // you need to add a field for each property accordingly to its name
        ->add('tournament', EntityType::class) // will output a select with all tournaments
        ->add('external_id', TextType::class)
        ->add('external_date', DateTimeType::class)

    $form->handleRequest($request) // will synchronize post values to the new entity

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) { // validate the form
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $filledEntity = $form->getData();

        $em->persist($filledEntity);
        $em->flush();

        return new JsonResponse(['id' => $filledEntity->getId()]);
    }

    if (0 < count($form->getErrors)) {
        return new JsonResponse(['errors' => $form->getErrors()]);
    }

    return new JsonResponse(['errors' => ['No data matching form type']]);
}
```

If you need fine tuned validation you can use constraint as annotations in your class properties.

see http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html

and http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#form-validation

Comment: I don't use an HTML form to fill in the data. There is no select with all tournaments, only an ID in JavaScript. Anyway, I found that Data Transformers should be the way to go, but I've followed the official guide closely yet it keeps giving me errors.

Comment: Ok, it works the same except the returns. I've updated my answer accordingly, hope that helped anyway.

Comment: My problem was that whatever I tried, the form was not getting submitted with the data I provided it. Either there were type errors or the form simply had no errors and no submit. But anyway, I've dropped the idea because there was too much headache and time spent trying to solve this when I already have working code without the form. Using the form results in a load of code bloat anyway, because I have to use a data transformer for the tournament property.